# Cannot load image from URI using picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I a having a problem in load picture in an imageview through uri. I am using picasso and my code is as below:
I have an object CreateImage with a function displayImageFromURI

```
fun displayImageFromURI(imageView: ImageView,uri: Uri?,context: Context){
    Log.e("url", uri.toString())
    Picasso.get()
        .load(uri)
        .fit().centerCrop()
        .into(imageView, object: com.squareup.picasso.Callback {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                val imageBitmap = (imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                val imageDrawable =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.resources, imageBitmap)
                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable)
            }

            override fun onError(e: java.lang.Exception?) {
                Log.e("error",e.toString())
            }
        })
}
```

I am calling this function from a fragment as below:

```
if (!photoUrl.equals("")) {
        Log.e("in photo url", photoUrl)
        val image = Uri.parse(photoUrl)
        CreateImage.displayImageFromURI(ivUploadQuestionImage, image, this)
    }
```

but my image is not being loaded in the imageview. The string photoUrl contains the link in string format as well. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Please put in your post the value of uri.toString(). At the log statement. Also of photoUrl ( showing how it looks like is enough if something is private)

Comment: @blackapps photourl is https://dev.litatrip.com/uploads/images/1599126680094_IMG_20200901_160228.jpg